# Javascript perform arithmetic on captured regexp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to replace my title from its default to `"*number* new messages | default"`

Here is the code I have, it changes from default to `1 new messages` fine, but it never goes above 1.

```
title = $('title').text();
regexp = /^(\d+)/

if (title.match(regexp))
  $('title').text().replace(regexp, (parseInt("$1")+1).toString())
else
  $('title').text('1 New Messages | Default')
```

Comment: Just curious, Why are you using `match` over `test` in this implementation? Also, can you provide an example (or examples) of what `$('title').text()` may have? (Finally, are you sure it's not `#title` or `.title` as the selector?)

Comment: Why are you doing this `parseInt("$1")` ? That will give you `NaN`

Comment: @Brad, title - is the title of the page, that selector should work.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: Touche, I had tunnel-vision and was thinking of only the body's contents. Good call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using a function as the second argument to [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), you also need to set the new value:

```
var title = $('title').text();
$('title').text(title.replace(regexp, function(m) { return parseInt(m, 10) + 1) }));
```

And, as usual, don't forget the radix argument when you call [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or you will be unpleasantly surprised sooner or later.

Comment: +1 I was not aware of the function as a 2nd argument.  This is a neat solution.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Also thanks for mentioning that I shouldn't assume that parseInt will assume base 10 by default in all browsers.

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee: I tend to think that leaving the second argument to `parseInt` optional is a bug in the JavaScript spec. You almost never want `parseInt` to guess the radix so parseInt's interface is (IMHO) broken by design. Can't change it now though :)

Answer (score 2):

I came across this recently and the issue is to do with calling a function within the second argument of the replace function.  The $1 is only valid if called directly in a string literal, not as a string argument to a function.

Another issue is that `$('title').text().replace(regexp, (parseInt("$1")+1).toString())` will return a string.  You need to pass the value you want to assign the text to as a function argument of the `text()` function like you have done in your else block.

Try this:

```
title = $('title').text();
regexp = /^(\d+)/

if (numToReplace = title.match(regexp))
  $(title).text(title.replace(regexp, (parseInt(numToReplace[1])+1).toString()))
else
  $('title').text('1 New Messages | Default')
```

And a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KFW4G/

Answer (score 0):

`replace` returns a new string, so you have to use `text` again to set the text to the result.